# Can I make Mercurial case-sensitive on file names on NTFS?

Tags: git, mercurial

Is there a way to make Mercurial treat `foo.txt` and `Foo.txt` as different?
So if I rename `foo.txt` to `Foo.txt`, it would see this change and alow to commit this to repository?

Currently, if I rename a file, Mercurial does not see any change and there is no way to commit the change (other than workarounds, like rename to `foo_.txt` first).

The backgrond is - I have a bunch of XML files which are processed to generate code and compile it to a DLL. File names and casing are important, as they become class names in target code.

---

Additional question: if this is not possible, would this be any different on Git?

Comment: Git on Windows doesn't discover this change either by default, and if you configure core.ignorecase to false then it gets superconfused when you rename a file without using `git mv`. Basically it sees a new file, because Test.txt isn't known to git but test.txt is, and it sees the old file because Windows says that test.txt exists and has the same metadata as in the repository. Basically, if you rename the file changing case, then add and commit it, the repository now contains 2 files with different casing but only one file on disk.

Comment: Can you try asking mercurial to rename the file for you, instead of it discovering that you renamed it using Windows? See if that makes a difference?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yes it does make a difference, it behaves correctly this way, exactly like with a normal rename. I also tested that the other clone of the repo will get the file physically renamed when updating to this revision. This is partially good news. But for us still a problem, as these XML files come from different development group and we just need to put them on top of previous version and have Mercurial find these changes. So it seems that discovering changes fails - is there any way to reconfigure it? I use TortoiseHg - could this be a problem with Tortoise instead?

Comment: Since Windows is case-insensitive, it sounds like the design decision to use the case of the filename isn't a good one.  Instead, put the class names in the XML data.

Comment: Thanks for comments guys. But I'm so unhappy about that :/

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this for Mercurial but there are mechanisms for making Windows operate an NTFS filesystem as case-sensitive in certain contexts.

https://superuser.com/questions/266110/how-do-you-make-windows-7-fully-case-sensitive-with-respect-to-the-filesystem

Summary:

> You can set the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\ dword:ObCaseInsensitive` registry value to `0`